# *ngFor Inside *ngIf - How to Rewrite it properly

Tags: angular, typescript

could some one tell me how to rewrite below *ngIF and *ngFor combination.?

***I'm aware about my issue is duplicate but pls understand, this is different.***

it's working as fine. but issue what am facing is that`<li></li>` tag color is not getting changed dynamically. But i could see `'active item'` classes are applying properly when sliding from one image to another in DOM.

Here, what i'm trying to achieve is, **i don't want show carousel indicator for single image item only**. As you can see, i'm rendering image dynamically. Everything is working fine except active class color change.

Please point my mistake where i'm doing wrong.

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="sliderDots"
        *ngIf="respDataList  &&  respDataList.length > 1">
        <ng-container >
            <li data-target="#myCarousel"
                *ngFor="let li of respDataList; let i = index" [attr.data-slide-to]="i"
                class="{{ (i == 0) ? 'active' : '' }}"></li>
        </ng-container>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div *ngFor="let document of respDataList; let i = index"
            class="{{ (i == 0) ? 'item active' : 'item' }}"
            [innerHTML]="document>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This sample demo i've created for some other purpose](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt1sxf)  i want to change it as mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: quick guidance : use `ngClass` instead of `class`, probably

Comment: but its working fine with ` class` already. initially i used `ngClass` but faced some issue so replaced it with simple `class`

Comment: Colors are changing for me .....

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators" id="adList" *ngIf="mockData.length > 1">
```

And you have no indicator for less than 2 elements

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5gvvj

to make single element only remove `//` line 16 in `app` component